# Energy conservation in Interplanetary orbit transfer

Tags: orbital-mechanics

When a spacecraft flys past a planet eg. Jupiter , its heliocentric energy increases dramatically allowing it to go further away. How is this possible without using any more rocket fuel?

Comment: As [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist) says, the energy is taken from the planet's orbital energy.

Comment: Are you sure "heliocentric energy" has any meaning?  Do you mean kinetic energy in the rest frame of the sun?